# C# Why Is The Form Size (this.Size) Greater Than The Form Maximum Size (this.MaximumSize)?

Tags: c#, size, this

I am changing the size and maximum size of the form based on the screen size and logging the results via Output/Console:

```
Screen scr = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(scr.Width, scr.Height);
this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(scr.Width, scr.Height);
Console.WriteLine(this.Size + " " + this.MaximumSize);
```

However, the output I get doesn't make sense (the first output is `this.Size`. The second output is `this.MaximumSize`):

```
{Width=1680, Height=1050} {Width=1680, Height=1010}
```

How is it that the form size is greater than the maximum size?

**EDIT 1:** I forget to put `Screen scr` instead of `scr`.

Comment: The location of this code is very important, we can't tell.  But high odds that you are doing it too early.  At which point you are not actually setting the form size, not yet, Winforms cares a lot about the ClientSize.  The actual outer form size depends on the size of the borders and the title bar.  Especially the latter depends a great deal on user preferences.  The real size is determined when the window is created, at which point MaximumSize is used, one of the few good reasons to use the Load event.

Comment: @HansPassant I made a custom form using buttons for minimizing maximizing and closing. I used a click event to trigger the form's size, in this case.

Comment: Sure, that will do it, the target Size is calculated from the ClientSize with the assumption that the window has standard chrome.  This will get sorted out when the window actually gets created.

Comment: So, should I use this.ClientSize to change the size?

Comment: It is not clear why you have to change anything.  What *actually* goes wrong at runtime?

Comment: @HansPassant I want the height of the form to be 1010 but it's 1050. How do I fix this

Comment: You are not telling us what actually goes wrong, 1050 is an expected value.  MaximumSize is applied when the window is created, Size will not be accurate until the Load event fires.  Move the code or just don't bother.

Comment: @HansPassant when the form loads, the size is set to `(800, 600)`. It only changes on the click event. I don't have a Load event. I put a method caller `SetWindowState();` after `InitializeComponent();` in the public method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The problem was I was using `WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximize` and this defaulted my height to the maximum size of the window (aka 1050). This was overriding `this.MaximumSize`.

To fix the problem, I used booleans that when true fix the size of the form.